# winform multiple select grid row and get row index of selected rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a databound gridview in my winform. I want to know how to get the index of Currently selected rows i.e multiple rows.
I am able to do this with a single row. but is there a way I can have a checkbox or something in which I can index of multiple rows.
The Image below will help u understand better of my requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First set `CellContentClick` event to your `DataGridView`.

```
dataGridView.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.onCellContentClick);
```

For every cell click it will invoke the following method. Here you can create a list and populate it with clicked row index.

```
public void onCellContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs cell)
{
   // Check whether selected cell is check box column, here 0 indicates the check box column.
   if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0)   
   {
      bool isChecked = (Boolean) dataGridView[cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;

      if(isChecked) 
      {
        // Below will give you the selected cell row index, for multiple rows you can populate those index in list or whatever you convenient with.
        cell.RowIndex;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataGridView.SelectedRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get all selected rows.

To select multiple rows:

```
DataGridView.MultiSelect = true;
```